# it about hindi text proccessing in in linux using c++

Tags: c++

How to do processing on hindi text using c++ in linux any suggestions.
I want to read a hindi text from file encoded in UTF-8 and process it that is to find a
specific word from that .  How can we do it??

Comment: You really need to give more information than that if you want an answer and not get marked down, or even worse closed.

Comment: what are you interested in? The reading of the file? The search? Getting the position of the word in the file? Finding out if the word is in the file? Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

The design of utf8 means that you don't have to take any special encoding specific steps. The C++ standard library functions that are based on `char` are all 8 bit clean, so they'll all work with utf-8 *(except for esoteric environments where `char` isn't 8 bits)*.

```
std::string word = /*the word you are looking for, encoded in utf8*/;
std::string fileContents = /*the file contents*/;

std::string::iterator location = fileContents.find(word);
```