# how to read hindi text from a file in c++?

Tags: c++, hindi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [it about hindi text proccessing in in linux using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043358/it-about-hindi-text-proccessing-in-in-linux-using-c)

A file contains hindi text. I want to read this file and perform some operations on text it contains. So, if anyone could please explain how to read it from file and handle it(or just print it).
Ex: if file contains

मै एक भारतीय हूँ।

then my program should read this content from file and print above text on standard output.
I want to perform it on Linux.

Direct code will be more beneficial.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043358/it-about-hindi-text-proccessing-in-in-linux-using-c posted by same user 2 hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the encoding. If your file is encoded in Unicode, you just have to use wide ANSI C functions (`fwscanf`, `fgetwc` and so on) you will be able to read any file in any language.

Comment: If i have file encoded in UTF-8 can you provide c++ code to read it??