# help for hindi programming

Tags: c++

```
#include<wchar.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

  fputws(L"मै एक भारतीय हूँ।",stdout);
 return 0;
}
```

?? ?? ?????? ??? is displayed when i run it on ubuntu
can anybody help me out?

Comment: Try printing the result of setlocale(LC_ALL, "").

Comment: Is that some ciphered text ?! :P

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043358 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044170 (same user, earlier today).

Comment: @ ereOn, It's a language.. Hindi.. From India.. :)

Comment: yes it is. and answer only if you know the answer. don't crack any PJs here on stackoverflow. i don't understand how you people managed to get that reputation on this site.

Answer (score 5):

Configure terminal to use Unicode.

Comment: I have configured my terminal UTF-8 . but still it prints the same o/p

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding method, not a code page.  You need to configure your terminal to have support for the Unicode character set that contains your language specific characters.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your terminal emulator is set to the proper encoding.